# Bootstrap Timepicker not show in RTL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I work with `RTLbootstrap`. Now I add [Timeticker](http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/) plugin in my form. But Timeticker dropdown not show in right of input and normal width.

Problem Pic:

[image]

I need to like this:

[image]

How do Fix This?

DEMO [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ2E4/)

Comment: RTL is itself "Right to left". That's why dropdown is in the left

Comment: @NishuTayal: What's your mean dropdown is in the left?

Comment: timepicker dropdown...if I'm not wrong,you want that in right side

Comment: please see http://jsfiddle.net/CZ2E4/

Comment: I use this  style and fixed :       '.bootstrap-timepicker-widget table tr {
        width: 150px;
    }
        .bootstrap-timepicker-widget table tr td:nth-child(1) {
            position: absolute;
            width: 62px;
            right: 93px;
        }
        .bootstrap-timepicker-widget table tr td:nth-child(3) {
            position: absolute;
            width: 62px;
            right: 0px;
        }
    .bootstrap-timepicker-widget table {
        height: 116px;
    }'

Answer (score 5):

this worked 100%

change style from **bootstrap-timepicker.min.css** or **bootstrap-timepicker.css** fllowing this rule on css;

```
 bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu{ padding: 4px}
```

change to :

```
    bootstrap-timepicker-widget.dropdown-menu{ padding: 4px;direction: ltr;right: auto}
```

Answer (score 1):

change style on the following rule,

```
.dropdown-menu{
  right: auto;
}
```

to as shown below.

```
.dropdown-menu{
  right:0;
}
```

and it'll be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Added to my css

> .datetime-picker-dropdown {
>       direction: initial !important; }

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
  list-style: none;
    direction:ltr !important;
}
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  margin: 2px 0;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 17em;
 direction:ltr !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey hosseinkhazaei, this answer could be improved if you commented on what is wrong with the Asker's code, and how this code you have fixes it.